# Keras: how to implement target replication for LSTM?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

Using examples from [Lipton et al (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03677), target replication is basically calculating the loss at each time step (except final) of the LSTM (or GRU) and averaging this loss and adding it to the main loss while training. Mathematically, it is given by -

[image: loss equation]

Graphically, it can be represented as -

[image]

So how do I go about exactly implementing this in Keras? Say, I have binary classification task. Let's say my model is a simple one given below -

```
model.add(LSTM(50))    
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', class_weights={0:0.5, 1:4}, optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

1. I think `y_train` needs to be reshaped/tiled from (batch_size, 1) to (batch_size, time_step) right?
2. The dense layer needs `TimeDistributed` to be applied correctly to the LSTM after setting `return_sequences=True`?
3. How do I exactly implement the exact loss function given above? Will `class_weights` need to be modified?
4. Target replication is only during training. How to implement validation set evaluation using only the main loss?
5. How should I deal with zero paddings in target replication? My sequences are padded to a `max_len` of 15 with average length being 7. Since the target replication loss averages over all the steps, how do I make sure it doesn't use the padded words in calculating the loss? Basically, dynamically assign *T* the actual sequence length.

Comment: When you say target replication, you do mean you want the loss to consider the exact same target for all steps? Literal copies? (This is easy). If not, then it's complicated.

Comment: Yeah, same target

Comment: FYI you can find a pure tensorflow implementation from the authors of the article at: https://github.com/aqibsaeed/Multilabel-timeseries-classification-with-LSTM/blob/master/RNN%20-%20Multilabel.ipynb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

So, for the targets, you need it shaped as `(batch_size, time_steps, 1)`. Just use:

```
y_train = np.stack([y_train]*time_steps, axis=1)
```

**Question 2:**

You're correct, but `TimeDistributed` is optional in Keras 2.

**Question 3:**

I don't know how class weights will behave, but a regular loss function should go like:

```
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy

def target_replication_loss(alpha):

    def inner_loss(true,pred):
        losses = binary_crossentropy(true,pred)

        return (alpha*K.mean(losses[:,:-1], axis=-1)) + ((1-alpha)*losses[:,-1])

    return inner_loss

model.compile(......, loss = target_replication_loss(alpha), ...)
```

**Question 3a:**

Since the above doens't work well with class weights, I created an alternative where the weights go into the loss:

```
def target_replication_loss(alpha, class_weights):

    def get_weights(x):
        b = class_weights[0]
        a = class_weights[1] - b
        return (a*x) + b

    def inner_loss(true,pred):
        #this will only work for classification with only one class 0 or 1
        #and only if the target is the same for all classes
        true_classes = true[:,-1,0]
        weights = get_weights(true_classes)

        losses = binary_crossentropy(true,pred)

        return weights*((alpha*K.mean(losses[:,:-1], axis=-1)) + ((1-alpha)*losses[:,-1]))

    return inner_loss
```

**Question 4:**

To avoid complexity, I'd say you should use an additional `metric` in validation:

```
def last_step_BC(true,pred):
    return binary_crossentropy(true[:,-1], pred[:,-1])

model.compile(...., 
              loss = target_replication_loss(alpha), 
              metrics=[last_step_BC])
```

**Question 5:**

This is a hard one and I'd need to research a little....

As an initial workaround, you can set the model with an input shape of `(None, features)`, and train each sequence individually.

---

### Working example without class_weight

```
def target_replication_loss(alpha):

    def inner_loss(true,pred):
        losses = binary_crossentropy(true,pred)
        #print(K.int_shape(losses))
        #print(K.int_shape(losses[:,:-1]))
        #print(K.int_shape(K.mean(losses[:,:-1], axis=-1)))
        #print(K.int_shape(losses[:,-1]))

        return (alpha*K.mean(losses[:,:-1], axis=-1)) + ((1-alpha)*losses[:,-1])

    return inner_loss

alpha = 0.6

i1 = Input((5,2))
i2 = Input((5,2))

out = LSTM(1, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True)(i1)
model = Model(i1, out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = target_replication_loss(alpha))

model.fit(np.arange(30).reshape((3,5,2)), np.arange(15).reshape((3,5,1)), epochs = 200)
```

### Working example with class weights:

```
def target_replication_loss(alpha, class_weights):

    def get_weights(x):
        b = class_weights[0]
        a = class_weights[1] - b
        return (a*x) + b

    def inner_loss(true,pred):
        #this will only work for classification with only one class 0 or 1
        #and only if the target is the same for all classes
        true_classes = true[:,-1,0]
        weights = get_weights(true_classes)

        losses = binary_crossentropy(true,pred)
        print(K.int_shape(losses))
        print(K.int_shape(losses[:,:-1]))
        print(K.int_shape(K.mean(losses[:,:-1], axis=-1)))
        print(K.int_shape(losses[:,-1]))
        print(K.int_shape(weights))

        return weights*((alpha*K.mean(losses[:,:-1], axis=-1)) + ((1-alpha)*losses[:,-1]))

    return inner_loss

alpha = 0.6
class_weights={0: 0.5, 1:4.}

i1 = Input(batch_shape=(3,5,2))
i2 = Input((5,2))

out = LSTM(1, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True)(i1)
model = Model(i1, out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = target_replication_loss(alpha, class_weights))

model.fit(np.arange(30).reshape((3,5,2)), np.arange(15).reshape((3,5,1)), epochs = 200)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. As for question 5, would using a `Masking` layer before the LSTM help?

Comment: I think so, but I don't have experience with masks to know what would happen in the loss function.

Comment: I don't think `target_replication_loss` is backpropagating to previous layers. Getting a `Incompatible shapes: [1000] vs. [1000,15]` error in the `loss_8/dense_10_loss/mul_2`

Comment: Hmmmm.... just for testing, if you remove the class weights does the error still occur?

Comment: @HMK, see the "working examples" I added to the answer. I believe Keras is creating a weight matrix shaped like `(batch, steps)` and trying to multiply it by our loss which is `(batch,)`. I created an example where I apply the weights directly in the loss, with the proper shape.